# What is the best way to use $state in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, vuex

I used to do `AngularJS` and now I wanna try to work with `Vue.js`.

But I have a simple question: what is the best way to use and access states? I saw so many solutions on Google but I can't find which one is the best for a beginner.

I used to use states like this :

```
$state.go('homework', { homework: homework.homework});
```

Can you give me an exemple of this code in Vue? Basically, go to homework and give him an homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Vue.js` it works with `Vuex`, the management library. You can find a documentation for state management in `Vue.js` [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) or and for `Vuex` [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/).

Example from the documentation for `Vuex`:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
})
```

Use your `Vuex` store in your app:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store
})
```

Access your state in a component:

```
this.$store.state.count
```

Change the state according to the example (`state.count++)`:

```
this.$store.commit('increment')
```

---

Edit:

To complete the answer with a example for your question. Declare

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    homework: "Example"
  },
  mutations: {
    setNewHomework (state, newHomework) {
      state.homework = newHomework
    }
  }
})
```

Set a new state for `homework`:

```
this.$store.commit('setNewHomework', 'New Homework')
```

Comment: So imagine I have an API class, is it best to put all my request inside the Vuex store? Or is it best to create the API class with the request and to save the results inside the Vuex store?

Comment: @JohnW2Smith `Vuex` should be the only source of truth. So you would collect data from your API, store in in your `Vuex` store and call the assigned states from the store in your components.

Comment: Thank you ! So I don't need to pass them with Vue Router, Vue router have only to navigate to views and the data (like a token) should be in the store, so I can reuse it on all my views?

Comment: @JohnW2Smith Correct. You can use `Vuex` without `vue-router` and the other way round. If you receive a token from your API, it´s the best way to store in in your `Vuex` store. Then you can only manipulate it the way you determinated before.

Comment: Ok ! That's so different from AngularJS.. but I understand now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

With `$state.go` I believe you are using `ui-router`.
In that case you should check out `Vue Router`. It works quite similar.

Comment: `$state.go` is state management in `angularjs`. OP asked for state management in `Vue.js`.

Comment: @Fabalance I am not sure but I think you misunderstand. https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#go. But anyway since you answer is accepted, you might be right.

Comment: OP asked how to do state management in `Vue.js` and gave an example how he did it in `angularjs`. Maybe thats why.